# Same combination of innocence and sand [Mark Twain Adventures]

Tags: word-usage

in the movie "The adventures of Mark Twain", what does sand mean in these dialogs:

00:07:39 More every day you remind me of my wife, Livy, God rest her.

00:07:44 Same combination of innocence and sand.

00:07:48 Same carefree laugh of a girl.

00:07:52 What happened to Livy, Mr. Twain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sand** (or "grit", or "stones") was sometimes used as an idiom for courage.

> sand (sænd)
>
> n
>
> [...]
>
> 5. *informal* US courage; grit
>
> [...]

- [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sand)

Sand, grit, or stones are sometimes used this way in Westerns (e.g., True Grit).

Comment: 'Stones', while meaning the same thing, has I believe a very different derivation.